# Spring boot - operation before repository save

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm supporter one code that have a lot of spread

```
dummyRepository.save(dummy)
```

but I need do some operations with "dummy" object before save, how can I do this?

Comment: dummyRepository is a instance of DummyRepository defined by
"public interface DummyRepository extends MongoRepository<Dummy, String> {}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at the annotations of the Java Persistence API (JPA):

```
@PrePersist
```

> Executed before the entity manager persist operation is
> actually executed or cascaded. This call is synchronous with the
> persist operation.

and

```
@PreUpdate
```

> Executed before the database UPDATE operation.

There are various ways to use them:

> This annotation may be applied to methods of an entity class, a mapped
> superclass, or a callback listener class.

The easiest way is to just add a Method in your Entity with this annotation. For example:

```
 @PrePersist
 @PreUpdate
 protected void onCreateOrUpdate()
 {
     setLastChangeDate(new Date());
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use Spring AOP for this kind of tampering